# Set CMake to values passed from cmd

Tags: cmake

So let's say that now I have this in `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
set(VAR1 1)
```

Is it possile to pass a value from the command line instead of putting "1" directly to the `CMakeLists.txt`? By passing some addition parameters while calling `cmake` in cmd, for example?

Thanks.

Comment: `cmake -D VAR1=1 ...`

Comment: Thanks for the answer and sorry for the duplicate. I used search but did not see that one for some reason.